# Entity Framework Code-First concurrency when deleted

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

In Entity Framework Code-First if the SaveChanges method fails because it's trying to update a record that a user just deleted on another machine, how can I tell EF to insert the record instead of update it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution (maybe not the best) is to put your code that call SaveChanges() inside a try/catch block. If an exception occurs, check if the record was deleted and set the state of the entity to EntityState.Added and call SaveChanges again.

Comment: How can I check if a record was deleted? Do I have to do this for each record in the context "transaction"?

Comment: I was assuming that you were trying to update one record. Maybe the best way to handle this scenario is mark the record as deleted (using soft delete), and when updating you always mark deleted = false.

Comment: I had thought of that alternative but it raises me up even more problems, I would have to change all the queries and include one more Where clause, I was expecting another kind of solution. Thanks anyway :)